# Disable the flash menu

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

how to disable the flash right click menu in the below code

```
<span style="width: 400px; height: 280px; position: relative; display: block; overflow: hidden; z-index: 2;" id="mObjCont0" class="MagicMagnifyPlusContainer"><span style="display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 280px; z-index: 200;"><embed flashvars="_p_big_images=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.magictoolbox.com%2Fstatic%2Fimages%2Fair2.jpg&amp;_p_small_images=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.magictoolbox.com%2Fstatic%2Fimages%2Fair1.jpg&amp;_p_width=400&amp;_p_status=2f3a4fccca6406e35bcf33e92dd93135&amp;_p_height=280&amp;_p_border_color=0x9b9b9b&amp;_p_border_width=0&amp;_p_magnifier=circle&amp;_p_magnifier_size=190&amp;_p_magnifier_size_x=190&amp;_p_magnifier_size_y=190&amp;_p_magnifier_border_width=3&amp;_p_magnifier_border_color=0x323856&amp;_p_magnifier_effect=fade&amp;_p_magnifier_filter=glow%2C%23000%2C0.5%2C5%2C5%2C2%2C100%2Cfalse&amp;_p_magnifier_time=200&amp;_p_magnifier_simulate=&amp;_p_lense_url=&amp;_p_lense_offset_x=0&amp;_p_lense_offset_y=0&amp;_p_lense_position=top&amp;_p_hide_cursor=0&amp;_p_callback=&amp;_p_thumb_change=click&amp;_p_thumb_change_delay=200&amp;_p_thumb_change_time=500&amp;_p_link_url=&amp;_p_link_window=_self&amp;_p_blur=0&amp;_p_transparency=100%25&amp;_p_show_immediately=0&amp;_p_show_immediately_x=0&amp;_p_show_immediately_y=0&amp;_p_disable_auto_start=0&amp;_p_containerDisplay=block&amp;_p_disable_expand=0&amp;_p_pause_on_click=0&amp;_p_init_on_click=1&amp;_p_change_time=500&amp;_p_background=&amp;_p_thumb_id=mt-0-0&amp;_p_progress_color=0xCCCCCC&amp;_p_progress_height=0&amp;_p_wmode=transparent&amp;_p_disable_image_clone=1&amp;_p_secure_domain=www.magictoolbox.com&amp;_p_disable_crossdomain=0&amp;_p_wheel_effect=20%25&amp;_p_baseurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.magictoolbox.com%2Fstatic%2Fmagicmagnifyplus%2F&amp;_p_img_id=mImg0" name="mObj0" src="http://www.magictoolbox.com/static/magicmagnifyplus/magicmagnifyplus.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" allowscriptaccess="always" base="." wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true" salign="lt" scale="exactFit" swliveconnect="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%">
```

you can directly view this code by simply paste this code in html file

remember already try param name="menu" value="false" but its not working

Comment: So is not a code machine. Please consider exposing you problem differently next time.

Answer (score 1):

You use `param name="menu" value="false"`.